# Having an issue with C# and constructors."ItemType.ItemType(string) is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Tags: c#, constructor

**I'm making an item system for my Unity game**, and I'm using C# to do it.  I have an abstract class called ItemType, which contains information about a particular type of items(such as its name, its weight, its market value, its id, etc.).  I then have to item classes, ItemSword, and ItemCoin, which inherit from the ItemType class.  I also have an ItemManager class, which instantiates ItemCoin and ItemSword and automatically assigns them an ID for me.  My problem is that **I'm getting an error with the constructors when I try to inherit the classes.**

The constructor for ItemType takes one parameter, a string called name.  When I go to do the constructor for ItemCoin, I make sure it calls the base class using

```
ItemCoin(string name): base(name){
//Stuff
}
```

just like it says on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx).

**The error is saying that "name" is inaccessible due to its protection level, as if I had made it private.**  I don't get how this is possible, though, since I'm not giving it *any* kind of access modifiers because it's a parameter.  ItemSword is not giving me this error, but that's likely because the compiler is still stuck on ItemCoin.

When I don't give "base" any parameters, it tells me that ItemType does not have a constructor with 0 parameters.  The same thing happens if I don't use "base" at all, or if I don't give it any constructor.

**For reference, here is my full source code.**

ItemType.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class ItemType{

    public int itemID; //The id of this item
    public string itemName; //The text name of this item

    public int stackSize = 99; //The maximum amount of this item allowed in a stack.  Use -1 for infinite
    public int maxAllowedInOneContainer = -1; //The maximum amount of this item allowed in a single container.  Use -1 for infinite.
    public int weight = 0; //The weight of this item
    public int marketValue = 0; //The standard price of this item in stores

    ItemType(string name){

        itemName = name;

    }

}
```

ItemCoin.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ItemCoin : ItemType {

    ItemCoin(string name): base(name){

        stackSize = -1;

    }

}
```

ItemSword.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ItemSword : ItemType{

    ItemSword(string name): base(name){
        maxAllowedInOneContainer = 1;
        stackSize = 1;
    }

}
```

ItemManager.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ItemManager {

    public const int MAX_ITEMS = 3200;

    private static ItemType[] itemList = new ItemType[MAX_ITEMS];
    public static int numberOfItems = 0;

    ItemManager(){

        /*When you make a new item, add it to this huge list of item declarations, or else it won't do anything!*/
        ItemSword sword = addItem(new ItemSword("Sword")); //Adds the sword item
        ItemCoin coin = addItem(new ItemCoin("Coin"));
    }

    public ItemType addItem(ItemType item){

        //Add the item to the list
        itemList[numberOfItems] = item;

        //Tell the item its id number
        item.itemID = numberOfItems;

        //Increment the total number of items by one.  This will be the id of the next added item.
        numberOfItems += 1;

        return item;

    }

    public int findItemID(string name){
        //Finds the item id for an item with a given name

        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){

            if (itemList[i].itemName == name){
                found = true;
                return itemList[i].itemID;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (found == false){
            throw new ItemIDNotFoundException();
        }

    }

    public string findItemName(int id){

        if (id >= itemList.Length){
            throw new ItemIDNotFoundException();
        }
        else{
            return itemList[id].name;
        }

    }

    public ItemType GetItem(int id){
        //Returns a reference(pointer) to the item type with a given id.
        return itemList[id];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Within classes, `private` is the default accessibility level, so by not specifying it, your constructor is private.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a constructor like this:

```
ItemType(string name){

    itemName = name;

}
```

it is private and can only be accessed by the class itself. `private` is the default for class members when no access modifier is specified.  In order to be able to use it from a subclass, you need to make it at least `protected`:

```
protected ItemType(string name)
{
    itemName = name;
}
```

Or you can make it `public` or `internal`.  Since this is an abstract class and it wouldn't make sense to access it from anything other the class itself or a subclass, `protected` is probably the most appropriate option.

Comment: Agreed. In an `abstract` class, it's quite meaningless to have a `public` (or `protected internal`) instance constructor. But he _could_ make it `internal` if he wanted to. However, `protected` is the most natural (and least restrictive) access level, for an instance constructor of an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

In classes, the default accessibility level is `private`. If you not specify it, then your constructors will be `private`.

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kcfb85a6.aspx)**;

> Note that if you do not use an access modifier with the constructor it
>   will still be private by default. However, the private modifier is usually used explicitly 
>   to make it clear that the class cannot be instantiated.